# Criar contas de e-mail usando Postfix para enviar no WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um site hospedado na digitalocean. Configurei o servidor com o EasyEngine para instalação de PHP, MySQL, Nginx, Postfix, WordPress, etc.

Porém, meu WordPress não está enviando e-mail, e como trata-se de uma loja (WooCommerce), preciso dessa função. Então minha duvida é: Será que preciso criar uma conta de e-mail no postfix para poder configurar o SMTP lá no WordPress? Atualmente o e-mail da loja esta alocado no Google App.

Answer (score 1):

Achei mais fácil usar o [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) pra enviar emails.

Uso esse código em produção:

```
$text = 'Olá Fulano';
$html = "<html>Olá <strong>Fulano de Tal</strong></html>";

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Assunto')
  ->setFrom(array('remetente@gmail.com' => 'Remetente'))
  ->setTo(array('destinatario@email.com.br'))
  ->setBody($text)
  ->addPart($html, 'text/html')
;

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465)
  ->setUsername('remetente@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('senha')
;
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);

if (!$result)
    http_response_code(500);
```

Comment: Acho que a idéia é "deixe quem entende de email cuidar do seu email". Dá pra fazer no braço? Dá. Mas, nossa, tem tanta outra coisa pra fazer :)